# find a string that contains specific value

Tags: python, string, pandas

How can I print all the dates in the dataframe (parsed to a string) which contain `2012-06` in the string

I dont remember which character symbolizes "ok after me are random characters, this part is not important"

i thought it was `(.*)` but its not

the purpose of this is to find and open all CSV files. so I thought I could get away with something like this in the end : `2012-06(.*).csv` to open all june 2012 files and "do stuff"

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

datelist = pd.date_range(pd.datetime(year = 2012, month = 6, day = 15), pd.datetime.today()).tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame(datelist)

for date in df[0]:

  d = str(date)

  if d == "2012-06(.*)":  

    print(d)
```

Comment: so basically you're looking for all filenames (strings) containing another string? why not `if your_string in your_filename: etc.`?

Comment: yeah, this seems the simplest solution, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use glob (https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to use `2012-06-*` pattern.

For example :

Let's say you have these files in a folder :

```
ls -l files
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff  0 Apr 30 13:57 2012-06-01_test.csv
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff  0 Apr 30 13:58 2012-06-15_my_file.csv
-rw-r--r--  1 julien  staff  0 Apr 30 13:58 2013-01-10_my_file.csv
```

You can do this :

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('files/2012-06*.csv')
print(files)
```

It will print :

```
['files/2012-06-15_my_file.csv', 'files/2012-06-01_test.csv']
```

With this list *files* you can iterate over and open each of them for example

Comment: this is exactly what I've been looking for.... https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 4):

I suggest use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df1 = df[df[0].astype(str).str.contains("2012-06")]
```

Or [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) for filtering in pandas:

```
df1 = df[df[0].astype(str).str.startswith("2012-06")]
```

---

```
print (df1)

            0
0  2012-06-15
1  2012-06-16
2  2012-06-17
3  2012-06-18
4  2012-06-19
5  2012-06-20
6  2012-06-21
7  2012-06-22
8  2012-06-23
9  2012-06-24
10 2012-06-25
11 2012-06-26
12 2012-06-27
13 2012-06-28
14 2012-06-29
15 2012-06-30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also query by `year` and `month`.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

datelist = pd.date_range(pd.datetime(year = 2012, month = 6, day = 15), pd.datetime.today()).tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame(datelist)
print(df[(df[0].dt.year == 2012) & (df[0].dt.month == 6)])
```